# How can I remove parentheses from WooCommerce subcategory product count

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, hook-woocommerce

On any default WooCommerce category page, it lists categories (product photo, title/link) with a number in parenthesis. For example, Finishing (6).

The page html looks like this:

```
<mark class="count">(6)</mark>
```

[image]

I tried this php to remove just the parenthesis, obviously that didn't work:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_subcategory_count_html( $mark_class_count_category_count_mark, $category ) {

    $mark_class_count_category_count_mark = ' <mark class="count">' . $category->count . '</mark>';

    return $mark_class_count_category_count_mark;
}
```

My goal is to style that count with a background color and border radius, which I can't now because the parenthesis gets in the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From where do you call this function? this function does nothing in itself. In short, you are using it wrong.

Try this instead

```php
function filter_woocommerce_subcategory_count_html ( $html, $category ) {
    $html =  '<mark class="count">' . esc_html( $category->count ) . '</mark>';
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', 'filter_woocommerce_subcategory_count_html', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about not being clear - I grabbed that code a few weeks ago from a site, saved it as a txt file. Didn't bookmark the site tho.